# Mark missing inbound JSON attributes

Tags: java, json, tomcat, spring-restcontroller

The web Client modifies some data and the selected attributes to be changed are random. 
The incoming request has been defined with all of the attributes, but if one is set (even to null), all others which were not sent are considered to be null by the server.

Is there a way to detect the "not sent" attributes from request, Any idea?

Comment: Even if you do not send the attributes in JSON, while parsing not sent attributes are initialized to null.

Comment: That repeats my question. But the at the point, where the incoming data are marshaled to a Java-object it might be possible to detect which of them were "missing" and at that point we could deal with it.